# Process.GetProcesses() and sort by memory usage

Tags: c#, sorting, process

I'm filling a ListBox (`listRAM`) with the running processes of the currently active user:

```
Process[] RAM = Process.GetProcesses();
Process[] sameAsthisSession = (from c in RAM where c.SessionId == Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId select c).ToArray();

foreach (var p in sameAsthisSession)
{
   listRAM.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
}

listRAM.Sorted = true;
```

The processes will be sorted alphabetically by `listRAM.Sorted = true;`.

I'm just curious, is it possible to sort them by **memory usage**, i.e. getting the memory usage of each process and adding them to the listbox through a loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var RAM = Process.GetProcesses();
var procs = RAM.Where(x => x.SessionId == Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId)
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.PrivateMemorySize64)
               .ToList();

foreach (var p in procs)
{
    listRAM.Items.Add(p.ProcessName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`listRAM.Sorted` causes the values within it to be sorted by their name.

If you wanted to sort by their memory usage, you would need to pre-sort the list and leave `listRAM.Sorted` as `false`.

Additionally if you are sorting by memory usage you will probably want to wrap the `Process` object in a helper object to display the RAM as part of the name, making more obvious the sorting being used.

For example:

```
class ProcessWrapper
{
    private Process _process;

    public ProcessWrapper(Process process)
    {
        _process = process;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _process.ToString() + " (" + _process.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1000000L + "M)";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce this down to a single LINQ statement:

```
var pNames = Process.GetProcesses()
                    .Where(x => x.SessionId == Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.PagedMemorySize64)
                    .Select(x => x.ProcessName);

foreach (var name in pNames)
    listRam.Items.Add(name);
```

[PagedMemorySize64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.pagedmemorysize64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "represents the current size of memory in the virtual memory paging file used by the process."

I haven't tested this, but you may have to add the value of PagedMemorySize64 and [NonpagedSystemMemorySize64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.nonpagedsystemmemorysize64%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the correct total memory usage.